# What is wrong with my C program

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, pthreads

I am trying to implement memory and different paging algorithms using threads. Now when I run my code, only the first two threads run, not the third. This is what it prints:

```
Thread one: Task 1, Sequence 1
Thread two: Task 1, Sequence 2
```

If anyone can tell me why my third thread isn't running, that would be very helpful.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t MemoryLock;
int k = 10;
int m = 10;
int n = 1000;
int seq = 0;
int start = 0; //for thread 2
int end = 10; //end is equal to value of k for thread 2

int disk[1000];

int MemoryLookupTable[10]; //Stores which variable is present in memory
int PhysicalMemory[10]; //Stores the value of the variables
int MetaTable[10]; //Meta level information

void least_recent(int i){
    int t, position, smallest, disk_num;

    t = 1;
    smallest = MetaTable[0];
    position = 0;

    while(t < m){
        if(smallest > MetaTable[t]){
            smallest = MetaTable[t];
            position = t;
        }
        t++;
    }

    disk_num = MemoryLookupTable[position];
    disk[disk_num] = PhysicalMemory[position];

    PhysicalMemory[position] = disk[i];
    MemoryLookupTable[position] = i;
    MetaTable[position] = seq;
}

void most_recent(int i){
    int t, position, largest, disk_num;

    t = 1;
    largest = MetaTable[0];
    position = 0;

    while(t < m){
        if(largest < MetaTable[t]){
            largest = MetaTable[t];
            position = t;
        }
        t++;
    }

    disk_num = MemoryLookupTable[position];
    disk[disk_num] = PhysicalMemory[position];

    PhysicalMemory[position] = disk[i];
    MemoryLookupTable[position] = i;
    MetaTable[position] = seq;
}

void random_order(int i){
    int r, disk_num;
    r = m * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));

    disk_num = MemoryLookupTable[r];
    disk[disk_num] = PhysicalMemory[r];

    PhysicalMemory[r] = disk[i];
    MemoryLookupTable[r] = i;
}

int fetch(int i){
    int x = 0;
    int x_i;

    x_i = disk[i];
    while(x < m){
        if(x_i == PhysicalMemory[x])
            return x_i;
        x++;
    }

    return -1;
}

void PageIn(int i){
    int x = 0;
    int present;

    present = fetch(i);
    if(present == -1)
        return; //Do not need to page in, since variable is already there.

    least_recent(i);
    //most_recent(i); I am testing each algorithm at a time, so these are commented out.
    //random_order(i);
}

void *t1(){
    int sum, task, r, i, fetched;
    sum, task = 0;
    r = rand() % (n - k) + k;

    for(i = 0; i < k - 1; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MemoryLock);
        seq++;
        fetched = fetch(i);
        if(fetched == -1){
            PageIn(i);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&MemoryLock);
            if(i = (k - 2))
           break;
        }
        sum = sum + disk[i];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MemoryLock);
   }

   sum = sum + disk[r];
   task++;
   printf("\nThread one: Task %d, Sequence %d", task, seq);

   return NULL;
}

void *t2(){
    int sum, task, i, fetched;
    sum, task = 0;

    for(i = start; i < end; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MemoryLock);
        seq++;
        fetched = fetch(i);
        if(fetched == -1){
            PageIn(i);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&MemoryLock);
            if(i = (end - 1)){
          sum = sum + disk[i];
          break;
            }
        }
        sum = sum + disk[i];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MemoryLock);
    }

    sum = sum + disk[i];
    task++;
    start++;
    if(end == n){
        start = 0;
        end = k;
    }
    else
        end++;
    printf("\nThread two: Task %d, Sequence %d", task, seq);

    return NULL;
}

void *t3(){
    int sum, task, r, i, fetched;

    for(i = 0; i < k; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MemoryLock);
        seq++;
        r =  n * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        fetched = fetch(r);
        if(fetched == -1){
            PageIn(r);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&MemoryLock);
            if(i = (k - 1)){
          sum = sum + disk[r];
          break;
            }
        }
        sum = sum + disk[r];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MemoryLock);
   }

   sum = sum + disk[r];
   task++;
   printf("\nThread three: Task %d, Sequence %d", task, seq);

   return NULL;
}

main(){
    int pt1, pt2, pt3, i, j, randNum;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        randNum = 200 * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        disk[i] = randNum;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < m; j++) //initializing array to empty
        MemoryLookupTable[j] = -1;

    if((pt1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, t1, NULL)))
         printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", pt1);

    if((pt2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, t2, NULL)))
         printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", pt2);

    if((pt3 = pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, t3, NULL)))
         printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", pt3);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL); 
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);  

    pthread_exit(0); 
}
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code to read through. Can you try to isolate the problem by removing code until you have a smaller test case?

Comment: When you have a complex program  it's usually a good idea to make a copy of the program and simplify it by removing everything that isn't relevant to the problem and just have the few lines remaining that reproduce the problem. Then you (and we) can concentrate only the relevant part of the code.

Comment: I am guessing there is something wrong with my third thread, which is t3. Or maybe when I declare the threads in main.

Comment: Your thread functions `t1()` etc should be defined `void *t1(void *arg)`, even if you don't use the argument.

Answer (score 3):

I run your program, the third thread executes successfully. Try to add `"\n"` to the end of `t3()`'s output:

```
printf("\nThread three: Task %d, Sequence %d\n", task, seq);
```

If there is no line break in the end of line, your terminal may not display it.